# 45 degree angle split background colour for website

Tags: html, css, background, responsive-design, angle

Can anyone tell me the best way to get a scaling split background effect like this for a responsive website. Using in HTML5 and CSS3: [image: Example background effect]

I've tried a gradient but get a jagged edge and would appreciate any thoughts before I get too deep in to another method. Ideally has to work back to IE9.

Thanks

Comment: Check out [css-tricks' tutorial on how to create triangles](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) . I believe this is a valid solution for some cases, since you can create multiple triangle and change their color.

You can also create a container with one color, and place a triangle above it with another color. This way you only actually create one triangle, but should get the desired effect.

Comment: @Shahar: Yeah I tried something like this but had problems getting the triangles to scale with the rest of the content as the screens got smaller. I'll have another look in to it.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps : http://codepen.io/ZsharE/pen/VYRPwW !

**HTML**

```
<div class="shape">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="shape-content">
      <h1>Diagonal background</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.shape {
    width: 100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    position: relative;
    background: #468d91;
}

.shape-content {
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin:0 auto;
  padding: 200px 15px 200px 15px;
}

.shape-content h1 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 15px;
    z-index: 9;
    position: relative;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #444444;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.top {
  position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:transparent transparent #3c888b #3c888b;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

**JS**

```
function angle() {
    var w = $(window).width();
    var h = $(".shape").height();
    $('.top').css('border-right-width', w - 3);
    $('.top').css('border-bottom-width', h - 3);
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).bind("load", function(){
        angle();
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
        angle();
    });

});
```